# How to pass a viewbag with RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got a controller which assign a value to the `ViewBag` and that `ViewBag` is used in the script,

this is my code, i have no idea whats wrong, i even tried using `TempData` but nothing happens everytime it shows that my `ViewBag` is null.

```
public ActionResult ChechUserNP(Login dd)
{
    if (dd.userid == "admin" && dd.pwd == "admin")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "DataGridView");
    }
    else
    {
        @ViewBag.Message = "MyMessage";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
}
```

```
<script>
    debugger;
    if (@ViewBag.Message !== null) {
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`TempData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tempdata) instead as it's specifically geared towards scenarios involving redirects.

```
TempData["Message"] = "MyMessage";
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
```

Comment: William so if we are using TemData how can i accept it in the script?

Comment: You should be able to read/access it much like you would other sources like the ViewBag (e.g. `@TempData["Message"]`).

Comment: So if im accessing it can i access it like if (@TempData["Message"] !== null) {

Comment: Is this an external script file? If so, you won't be able to access it that way. If you intend to use the value directly in Javascript, I'd recommend wrapping the value in single-ticks and store it in a variable, e.g. `var message = '@TempData["Message"]';` and then you can just reference that variable within your Javascript code e.g. `if(message !== '') { ... }`.

It just depends on if you are referencing it _in_ Javascript or in Razor.